# Как создать систему движения объектов по принципу эстафеты в C#?

Tags: c#

Нужно создать систему из нескольких объектов, которые двигаются как бегуны на эстафете: бежит только один, пока не добегает до другого. Если дистанция до следующего объекта становится меньше passDistance, объект перестаёт быть «бегуном», им становится следующий объект. И так по кругу.

Текущий код:

```
public class Runners : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform[] _runners;
    [SerializeField] float _speed;
    private Transform _currentRunner;
    private Transform _nextRunner;
    private Vector3 _currentRunnerPosition;
    private Vector3 _nextRunnerPosition;
    int _runnerIndex;
    float _distance;
    float _passDistance = 0.01f;

    
    void Start()
    {
        _currentRunnerPosition = _runners[0].position;
        _runnerIndex = 0;
        _nextRunnerPosition = _runners[_runnerIndex++].position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        _currentRunnerPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(_currentRunnerPosition, _nextRunnerPosition, Time.deltaTime * _speed);

        ChangeRunner();
    }

    void ChangeRunner()
    {
        _distance = Vector3.Distance(_nextRunnerPosition, _currentRunnerPosition);

        if (_distance <= _passDistance)
        {
            _runnerIndex++;

            if (_runnerIndex >= _runners.Length)
            {
                _runnerIndex = 0;
            }

            _nextRunner = _runners[_runnerIndex];
            _currentRunner = _nextRunner;
            _nextRunnerPosition = _runners[_runnerIndex++].position;

            _currentRunner.LookAt(_nextRunner);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `_currentRunnerPosition` и `_nextRunnerPosition` - это _структура_ `Vector3d`, ты по сути меняешь копии, а не значения в самом объекте. У тебя есть `_currentRunner` и `_nextRunner`, у них есть `position` - их и нужно использовать. И ещё в `_runners[_runnerIndex++]` постфиксный инкремент подложил тебе свинью - сначала будет взят элемент с индексом `_runnerIndex` и лишь потом `_runnerIndex` будет увеличен на единицу.

Comment: спасибо!!! все получилось)